# Background computation in ASP.NET MVC (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently doing an ASP.NET MVC (C#) project. I have a controller's method named "index" that is consuming a web service and this controller's method will return a value. Here are the codes:

```
  public ActionResult index()
 {

     ContactlessTerminal.wsContactlessTerminal objContactlessTerminal = new ContactlessTerminal.wsContactlessTerminal();
        string strMessage = objContactlessTerminal.fnMakeContactlessPayment(); 

        if (strMessage.Equals("00"))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "00";

        }
        else if(strMessage.Equals("11"))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "11";
         } 

    return View(); 
 }
```

The "index" view will retrieve the ViewBag's value returned by the controller's index method and then the "index" view will display the value of the ViewBag.
However, there is some performance issue. The consumption of the web service is taking too long hence it would take some time to get the "index" view to load finish.

So I tried to modify the codes by putting "the codes that are consuming the web service" in another thread. Here are the codes:

```
         public ActionResult index()
         {
              Thread thread = new Thread(testing);
              thread.Start();
              return View();
          }

           public void testing()
           {
                  ContactlessTerminal.wsContactlessTerminal objContactlessTerminal = new ContactlessTerminal.wsContactlessTerminal();
                string strMessage =  objContactlessTerminal.fnMakeContactlessPayment(); 

           if (strMessage.Equals("00"))
           {
              ViewBag.Message = "00";

           }
            else if(strMessage.Equals("11"))
           {  
            ViewBag.Message = "11";
           }   


            }
```

However, the "index" view will NOT be able to retrieve the ViewBag returned by the
index method of the controller as the index view would have already finish loading the entire page before the consumption of the web service is completed.
Basically, first of all, I wanna display a loading "GIF" in the index view to indicate that it is processing something in the background. And when the web service consumption is done, the index view will display the viewbag value returned by the methods of the controller.

Can anyone tell me how I can run the method "testing" in a background and after the web service consumption is completed, it will inform the "index" view to display the ViewBag returned by the index method of the controller.

Comment: You can't make _asynchronous_ server side because View will (may) be rendered and returned before job is completed (and time to render the view should be negligible compared to contacting WS). What you should do is to make it asynchronous client side. Render the view without that content and start from client an AJAX call to gather required data (eventually you may use a partial view rendered server side)

Comment: 1 Simple view without the api call.  2 ajax call on the view to return a partial (on your mvc controller) 3 partial view that returns the result of the api call

Comment: Alternatively, look at [signalr](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Answer (score -1):

What is the purpose of running a separate thread at all for you? If you cannot return a view immediately and have to wait for the result of task, there is no point in running it in a background.

If you want to free some resources (i.e. threads) if your long-running process is waiting for some services over network you will have to make you controller action async and run your background thread in a separate task, e.g.:

```
return await Task.Run(testing());
```

If you do some heavy computations or don't wont to bother, you can just use

```
Task.Run(testing()).Wait();
```

Though there will be no point in doing that really as I mentioned before.

If you really want to achieve update on the client side, you'll just have to make ordinary web api call and call it using AJAX from client-side, preferably using some framework like Knockout, Angular, React, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `async` patter in .Net. For example:

```
private Task<string> MakeContactlessPaymentAsync()
{
     TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
     Task.Run(() =>
     {
         ContactlessTerminal.wsContactlessTerminal objContactlessTerminal = 
              new ContactlessTerminal.wsContactlessTerminal();
         var strMessage = objContactlessTerminal.fnMakeContactlessPayment();
         tcs.SetResult(strMessage);
      });
     return tcs.Task;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> GizmosAsync()
{
    var result = await MakeContactlessPaymentAsync();       
    return View(result); //return the string as a model for that view
}
```

**EDIT**

[More info on MVC async](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: How does this help you render a view and then update the view based on an async result?

Comment: This is a complete misunderstanding of how asynchronous programming works in .NET. I suggest you review how it works and be careful not to spread misinformation about it in the future: async is hard enough without bad info out there.

Comment: @mason can you be more specific? I've seen methods like that being used in MVC and had no problem.

Comment: This will not help the view return to the client any faster. The call to the web service takes a certain amount of time, and that amount of time does not change just because it's being run in a task.  The `GizmosAsync` function will not return any faster. In fact, it's likely to be slower now because of the introduced overhead (not much, but a bit).